# Suggestions to improve query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm running the following query on our SQL Server DB.
The query takes at least 20 minutes to complete. I don't have permissions on the db to run execution plan

Thoughts or suggestions on what to try would be appreciated

```
SELECT

    UsageDate,
    --convert(date,dateadd(day, 22 - 1,dateadd(month,cast(datepart("MM", dateadd("d",-21, getdate()-2)) as int)- 1,dateadd(year,cast(datepart("yyyy", dateadd("d",23,getdate()-2)) as int) - 2000,'2000-01-01'))) ) AS BILLING_CYCLE_START_DT,
    (sum(MVNO301TotUsg)-sum(ROAMING_3G_LTE)) MB,
    sum(ROAMING_3G_LTE)ROAMING_3G_LTE,
    case when convert(date,UsageDate) = convert(date,dateadd(day, 9 - 1,dateadd(month,cast(datepart("MM", dateadd("d",-8, getdate()-2)) as int)- 1,dateadd(year,cast(datepart("yyyy", dateadd("d",10,getdate()-2)) as int) - 2000,'2000-01-01'))) )
    then 100000000  else 0 end as BeginBaseAvgMB

    FROM 
    (
    select convert(date,EVENT_DT) UsageDate,
    sum((USAGE_KB_3G+LTE_USAGE_KB+EHRPD_USAGE_KB)/1024)AS MVNO301TotUsg,
    0 ROAMING_3G_LTE
    from [spmp].[dbo].SubscriberCombinedUsageallmvnos USG with (NOLOCK)
    JOIN aMVNO.dbo.Subscribers S with (NOLOCK) ON USG.subscriberkey =S.subscriberkey
    left Join aMVNO.dbo.exMVNOs_Realm_RISE RLM with (NOLOCK) ON S.SubscriberNumber = RLM.SBSCR_NBR
    where (RESELLER_ID = 'a9')
    and convert(date,EVENT_DT) between dateadd(d,-33,GETDATE()) and dateadd(d,-2,GETDATE()) 
    group by convert(date,EVENT_DT)

UNION ALL
SELECT

    convert(date,EVENT_DT) UsageDate,
    0 AS MVNO301TotUsg,
    sum(DOMESTIC_ROAM_3G + INTERNATIONAL_ROAM_3G +GSM_3G +ROAMING_LTE_KB)/1024 ROAMING_3G_LTE
    from [spmp].[dbo].SubscriberCombinedUsageallmvnos USG with (NOLOCK)
    JOIN aMVNO.dbo.Subscribers S with (NOLOCK) ON USG.subscriberkey =S.subscriberkey
    left Join aMVNO.dbo.exMVNOs_Realm_RISE RLM with (NOLOCK) ON S.SubscriberNumber = RLM.SBSCR_NBR
    JOIN [aMVNO].[dbo].[BusinessDate] BD WITH (NOLOCK) ON convert(date,USG.EVENT_DT) =convert(date,BD.DT)
    where 
    (RESELLER_ID = 'a9')
    and convert(date,EVENT_DT) between dateadd(d,-33,GETDATE()) and dateadd(d,-2,GETDATE()) 

    GROUP BY 
    convert(date,EVENT_DT)
    )Z
    group by UsageDate

ORDER BY USAGEDATE
```

Comment: If you don't have permission to execution plan, then assign that task to someone who does.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
    and [QUERY PLAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: Most likely you need indices on columns that are apart of the join clause or where clause.

Comment: @BrandonKearby Yes, but how you test if the index are being use if can't check the explain plan?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I understand you're flying blind. If you can verify if there exists indices on the columns you are joining on or using in the where clause, it would be a good starting point.